# Как вывести информацию о строке в MySQL с проверкой на нахождение

Tags: python, mysql

делаю свою программу и хочу чтобы пользователь писал никнейм игрока в программе и он проверялся в моей базе данных (MySQL), если находится то выводит его данные из строки, а если нету то выводит print что такой игрок не найден в базе данных.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Сначала разберитесь, как вы это бы делали без `python`, просто из консоли БД: `select ... from ... where ...`, а дальше уже разбирайтесь с запросами из питона.